# How can I insert a row and append on a row number to enforce uniqueness?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table of `users` with emails.

The `users` have both `user_id` and `email` columns

I also have a list of `user_referral_codes`.

The `user_referral_codes` have a `user_id` which is a foreign key on the `user_id` of the user. It also has a `referral_code` column.

The `referral_code` will be the first part of a users' `email`.

If the email is `johnsmith99@gmail.com` then the `referral_code` will be set to `johnsmith`.

This works just fine:

```
`INSERT INTO flock_auth.user_referral_codes (user_id, referral_code)
VALUES($1, LEFT(LEFT($2, strpos($2, '@') - 1), 12));`
```

However, there may be two emails added one after another that match such as:

`johnsmith@gmail.com` and `johnsmith@aol.com`

In that case, I would want the second insertion to become:

`johnsmith1`.

For the initial `UPDATE` of existing users and referral codes, this works just fine:

```
UPDATE auth.user_referral_codes urc
    SET referral_code = (
      LEFT(LEFT(email, strpos(email, '@') - 1), 12)
      || (CASE WHEN seqnum > 1 THEN (seqnum-1)::TEXT ELSE '' END)
    )
    FROM (
      SELECT
        auth.users.*,
        row_number() OVER (
          PARTITION BY LEFT(LEFT(email, strpos(email, '@') - 1), 12)
          ORDER BY id
        ) AS seqnum
      FROM auth.users
    ) AS u
  WHERE urc.user_id = u.id;
```

I've attempted to adapt this code for insertions.

```
INSERT INTO auth.user_referral_codes (user_id, referral_code)
  SELECT (
    $1,
    LEFT(LEFT(email, strpos(email, '@') - 1), 12)
    || (CASE WHEN seqnum > 1 THEN (seqnum-1)::TEXT ELSE '' END)
    )
    FROM (
      SELECT
        auth.users.*,
        row_number() OVER (
          PARTITION BY LEFT(LEFT(email, strpos(email, '@') - 1), 12)
          ORDER BY id
        ) AS seqnum
      FROM auth.users
    ) AS u
  WHERE $1 = u.id;
```

The error comes back as: `INSERT has more target columns than expressions`

How can I make this work?

Comment: I think your outer select is unnecessary and likely the problem...  if you roll the parameter into the first inner query, I think that's probably the syntax error.

Comment: I've updated that, thanks. I have a new error: `INSERT has more target columns than expressions`

Answer (score 1):

Without going into your code, notionally I would do something like this:

```
with parsed as (
  select
    email,
    left (split_part (email, '@', 1), 12) as user_id,
    row_number() over
        (partition by left (split_part (email, '@', 1), 12) order by id) - 1 as rn
  from auth.users
)
select
  email,
  case
    when rn > 0 then user_id || rn
    else user_id
  end as user_id
from parsed
```

You could get away without the CTE, but it does make things a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

This now works:

```
INSERT INTO auth.user_referral_codes (user_id, referral_code)
  SELECT
    $1,
    LEFT(LEFT(email, strpos(email, '@') - 1), 12)
    || (CASE WHEN seqnum > 1 THEN (seqnum-1)::TEXT ELSE '' END)
    FROM (
      SELECT
        auth.users.*,
        row_number() OVER (
          PARTITION BY LEFT(LEFT(email, strpos(email, '@') - 1), 12)
          ORDER BY id
        ) AS seqnum
      FROM auth.users
    ) AS u
  WHERE $1 = u.id;
```

The issue was extraneous parentheses and over nesting of the select statements.